# Counting occurrences in an array that has more than 1 key

Tags: php, arrays, counting

I'm trying to get the occurrences of an array taking in count 1 key value, for example:

```
 $newarray[0] = [
                    'id' => '2',
                    'date' => '2016-04-22'
                    ];
 $newarray[1] = [
                    'id' => '2',
                    'date' => '2016-04-13'
                    ];
 $newarray[2] = [
                    'id' => '2',
                    'date' => '2016-04-12'
                    ];
 $newarray[3] = [
                    'id' => '1',
                    'date' => '2016-03-11'
                    ];
 $newarray[4] = [
                    'id' => '2',
                    'date' => '2016-03-05'
                    ];
 $newarray[5] = [
                    'id' => '1',
                    'date' => '2016-03-01'
                    ];
```

I want to transform this, to something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [date] => 2016-03-11 [occurences] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [date] => 2016-04-22 [occurences] => 4 )  )
```

I tried doing this:

```
$cleanarray;
$newarray2=$newarray;
$newarray;
$k=0;
$num=1;

for($i=0; $i<count($newarray); $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<count($newarray2); $j++){
        if($newarray2[$j]["id"]==$newarray[$i]["id"]){
          $num++;
        }        

    }
    $cleanarray[$k] = [
                    'id' => $newarray[$i]["id"],
                    'date' => $newarray[$i]["date"],
                    'occurences' => $num
                ];
    $k++;
  $num=0;
}
```

But a lot of items repeat, with the same occurrences but several times, and in other cases the repeated items (with same id) would have different occurrences, so I don't know what can I do, I know that there is a function of:

```
$occurences = array_count_values($array);
```

But it doesn't work in this case, how can I approach to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($newarray as $arr){
   if(!in_array($arr['id'],array_keys($final_array))){
      $final_array[$arr['id']] = $arr;
      $final_array[$arr['id']]['occurences'] = 1;
   }else{
     $final_array[$arr['id']]['occurences'] += 1;
   }
}
$final_array= array_values($final_array);
print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/847242

Note:- if you want final array to be ascending order of id then use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function like below:-

```
function cmpId($a, $b) {
    return ($a['id'] - $b['id']);
}

usort($final_array, "cmpId");
print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/847245

Comment: AlivetoDie see my answer for leaner process.

Answer (score 1):

I know what are you looking for, but I think this could solve your problems:

```
$newarray[0] = [
                'id' => '2',
                'date' => '2016-04-22'
                ];
$newarray[1] = [
                'id' => '2',
                'date' => '2016-04-12'
                ];
$newarray[2] = [
                'id' => '2',
                'date' => '2016-04-12'
                ];
$newarray[3] = [
                'id' => '1',
                'date' => '2016-03-11'
                ];
$newarray[4] = [
                'id' => '2',
                'date' => '2016-03-05'
                ];
$newarray[5] = [
                'id' => '1',
                'date' => '2016-03-01'
                ];

foreach($newarray as $key => $value){
    if(isset($found[$value['id']][$value['date']])) {
        $found[$value['id']][$value['date']]++;
    } else {
        $found[$value['id']][$value['date']] = 1;
    }
}
print_r($found);
```

this will return something like:-

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [2016-04-22] => 1
            [2016-04-12] => 2
            [2016-03-05] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2016-03-11] => 1
            [2016-03-01] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using temporary keys for this process will be the most performant way.  Temporary keys simplify the output array task, requiring less and faster checking.  If you wish to sort on `id` after the result array is generated, the temporary keys allow a simple `ksort()` call.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/209639cd3b33004d89996b5215dc1446cd15124c))

```
$newarray=[
        ['id' => '2','date' => '2016-04-22'],
        ['id' => '2','date' => '2016-04-13'],
        ['id' => '2','date' => '2016-04-12'],
        ['id' => '1','date' => '2016-03-11'],
        ['id' => '2','date' => '2016-03-05'],
        ['id' => '1','date' => '2016-03-01']
];

foreach($newarray as $a){
    if(!isset($result[$a['id']])){
        $result[$a['id']]=array_merge($a,['occurrences'=>1]);  // use id as temp key, preserve first found date
    }else{
        ++$result[$a['id']]['occurrences'];  // only update occurrences to preserve date
    }
}
ksort($result);  // optionally sort on id ASC
var_export(array_values($result));  // remove temporary keys from first level and print to screen
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'date' => '2016-03-11',
    'occurrences' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'date' => '2016-04-22',
    'occurrences' => 4,
  ),
)
```